# A regular expression to match the same letter one or more times

Tags: java, regex

I need a regular expression that matches a string made of a single letter repeated one or more times.
For instance the regular expression must match: 
a
b
bb
aa
cccc
ddddd

But must not match 
ab 
bbc
ddddddddde
ac
cde
art.

I am using Java.

Comment: you are not clear enough, not even with your example, second one also have cc

Comment: Regex for what? Which language are you using?

Comment: I tried this: ([a-z])\1+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(In your current question, I believe there is a typo. I assume that `cc` should *not* be matched.)

```
([a-zA-Z])\1*
```

The parentheses denote a capture group. The `\1` is a backreference to the first capture group.

That will work with `java.util.regex.Matcher.matches`, but if you use something like `java.util.regex.Matcher.find` which allows subsequence matches, you will want

```
^([a-zA-Z])\1*$
```

to make sure it matches the entire input.

Comment: I would add ^ and $, otherwise +1

Comment: I think the word-boundary, or *some* boundary, is a requirement. He says he wants to match `aa`, but not `ab`.